# Insert to MySQL fails with error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a Python script that I have been using many times before to load CSV data into MySQL tables.

I modified the script for a very simple insert but it fails and I can't see why.

I've gone through the MySQL documentation of the Python connector, compared my syntax and I went through all the related articles on Stackoverflow but I can't find the reason. I've also checked the quotes I'm using as that is a common error.

Perhaps someone can help:

```
if row[0]:
   s=row[0]
   d=s[s.rfind('/')+1:len(s)-4]

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `tab` (`did`) VALUES (%s)",(d))
```

I've checked print(d) and d is populated correctly.

The error I'm getting is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%s)' at line 1

If anyone can spot the (probably very silly) error, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `tab` (`did`) VALUES (%s)",(d))
```

the `(d)` passed as params is a string with parentheses around it, not a tuple.

Here's how a mysql-connector [cursor checks its params](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/cursor.py#L498):

```
if params is not None:
    if isinstance(params, dict):
        for key, value in self._process_params_dict(params).items():
            stmt = stmt.replace(key, value)
    elif isinstance(params, (list, tuple)):
        psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
        stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
        if psub.remaining != 0:
            raise errors.ProgrammingError(
                "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
```

So in your case though *params* is not `None`, it is not something accepted as params either and parameter substitution does not take place.

The fix then is simply to pass a tuple to `cursor.execute()` (a `list` works too):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `tab` (`did`) VALUES (%s)", (d,))
```

Comment: This is working, thank you! I had tried similar things before but didn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I think your string formating is wrong. It should probably be:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `tab` (`did`) VALUES (?)",d)
```

But you should check in the docs for your database library. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the placeholder in the query.

Comment: That would be an SQL injection point then. `cursor.execute(stmt, args)` is the correct way. String formatting / concatenating is the way to disaster.